Reference request: scalar $O(N)$ gauge theory
I am interested in scalar $O(N)$ gauge theory and what you can do with it. Is there a standard reference section in a textbook/monograph/paper/whatever that has a decent overview?
Wikipedia has a surprisingly okay treatment of some of the basics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_theory#An_example:_Scalar_O(n)_gauge_theory), with emphasis on it as a pedagogical example of a gauge field, but there is no reference to indicate whether this comes from a specific text.
The types of questions I am interested in: what (if anything) can you do with such a theory, i.e. is it useful for modelling anything in the real world? What do the propagators and other correlation functions look like/how do you compute them? What do the Feynman diagrams/perturbative expansions look like? What happens if you couple it to another scalar $O(N)$ gauge theory (with a different mass)?

For large $N$ stuff, a good reference is https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9810198

@Prahar that looks like it could be an answer :)

If you’re interested in the large N version of these models, then a good reference is https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9810198
